# Outrunner motor

Tags: motor, connector

I'm building a flying copter and I've tried to control the speed of it's motors. All worked just perfect: I had a standard motor (with brushes) which had two wires, I've applied different input voltage and controlled it's speed.

The problem was, it was way too powerless... I've ordered a nice [outrunner motor](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/uh_viewItem.asp?idProduct=6247), but it has THREE wires, so this confused me much. How do I connect it? And how do I adjust it's speed?

Thanks much!

Comment: It's a brushless DC motor for which you use a brushless DC motor driver. In RC lingo that would be brushless ESC.

Comment: I have an arduino board and I do not want to use any other ones. Is it possible to connect the motor to it and to control its speed?

Comment: No. It is not possible to safely control a motor only with Arduino. You'll be able to produce the needed waveform for the motor using Arduino, but you'll need additional board with the transistors which will actually drive the motor itself using the signals generated by the Arduino. Also don't try to power such a motor directly using Arduino's power supply, or you will most likely damage it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm too tired at the moment to provide a full answer, but searching for `BLDC driver` will provide results. One of the first images on Google for me was [here](http://letsmakerobots.com/node/2876) in the middle of the page and that could work well with Arduino and some modifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Brushless motor.

[image: BLDC motor]

The thing about brushless motors is that an electronic circuit is required to switch the current between the coils as the magnetic part spins.

You need an [Electronic Speed Controller](http://www.rctoys.com/rc-toys-and-parts/HA-X-20-PRO/RC-PARTS-SPEED-CONTROLLERS-HACKER.html) to make it work. This contains all of the switching parts, and it also (magically) able to detect the position of the rotor, so that it knows exactly when to switch the current from one coil to another.

[image: Brushless ESC]